# Is there a way to blank 2 of 3 monitors with a shortcut or hotkey and leave primary monitor on?

Tags: nvidia, keyboard, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, monitor

I am only staying with windows because of a feature that so far I cannot find that linux has. i am trying to find a way to blank 2 specific monitors and leave my primary monitor on. Preferably with a bash or with keyboard. This will be used when watching a video on the primary screen and not needed the other 2 monitors. IE the setup I have in windows is a program that allows me to "blank" any monitors i want with a keyboard shortcut. I have a nvidia gfx card.

Answer (score 2):

I would tun `xrandr` to find out how my outputs were named and then, assuming my three montiors are called `DVI-I-2`, `DVI-I-2` and `DVI-I-3`, use the following to leave `DVI-I-1` on while toggling 2 and 3:

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-2 --off --output DVI-I-3 --off
xrandr --output DVI-I-2 --auto --output DVI-I-3 --auto
```

How you bind that into your workflow is up to you.

I haven't tested chaining multiple `--output` arguments (I only have two monitors), so you may need to split each command in two. And if `--auto` doesn't work, setting `--mode` explicitly should. `man xrandr` will show you the light.

Comment: Will it be possible to reverse the command to on or would I have to manually hit the power button to turn them back on?

Comment: The second line is the one that turns them back on (or should do - as I go onto say, you might need to explicitly specify a mode)